# Сериализация дерева в XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

У меня есть Xml файл полученный при сериализации дерева. У дерева в каждой ветке, разное кл-во "под веток". Вопрос заключается в том, что как мне при помощи средств System.XML переходить по этим веткам, что бы добавлять новые? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Так вроде ж ничего сложного нету.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var root = doc.Root;
var firstLevelBranches = root.Elements();
// добавим к каждой ветке по одной подветке
foreach (XElement branch in firstLevelBranches)
{
    var subbranch = new XElement("sub");
    branch.Add(addedSubbranch);
}
doc.Save(filename);
```

---

Для вашего примера всё тоже просто.

```
// вспомогательная функция
string GetFolderName(XElement folder)
{
    return (string)folder.Element("name").Value;
}

// ещё одна
XElement GetSubfolderByName(XElement folder, string name)
{
    return folder.Element("folders")
                 .Elements().Where(e => GetFolderName(e) == name)
                 .Single();
    // бросит исключение, если такого подкаталога нету
}

// ну и ещё одна
XElement CreateFileEntry(string name, string path)
{
    return
        new XElement("FileContent",
            new XElement("name", name),
            new XElement("path", path)
        );
}

var main = GetSubfolderByName(root, "Main");
var folder1 = GetSubfolderByName(main, "Folder1");
folder1.Element("files").Add(
      CreateFileEntry("file1.TXT", @"Main\Folder1\file1.TXT"));
```

Comment: Просто у меня при помощи дерева реализуется файловая система. и Мне допустим надо в это систему добавить файл используя адрес допустим 
"Main\folder1\folder2\folder5\file.txt"
как мне переходить по веткам?

Comment: @Maksisyan: Зависит от представления. Как будет такой элемент выглядеть в вашем XML-файле?

Comment: <pre>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Folder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>Container</name>
  <path>Container</path>
  <folders>
    <Folder>
      <name>Folder1</name>
      <path>Main\Folder1</path>
      <folders />
      <files>
        <FileContеnt>
          <name>Вкладки.txt</name>
          <path>Container\Folder1\Вкладки.txt</path>
        </FileContеnt>
      </files>
    </Folder>
  </folders>
  <files />
</Folder>
</pre>
Вот так выглядит дерево с одной папкой.Допустим я хочу добавить в Folder1 ещё один file1.TXT

Comment: @Maksisyan: Всё просто. Почитайте примеры на LINQ-to-XML. Добавил в ответ.